# Hard drive not recognized anymore, recording of noise included

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

Yesterday I was doing a monthly backup on a **Samsung HD502IJ** 500GB HD and, when it was getting to end of the backup, there was an *I/O error*. I tried running a `fsck` on the drive and it said the filesystem was damaged. While trying to fix it, it started asking too many questions, so I decided to cancel the `fsck` and run `fsck -y` instead, so it would give it a *yes* automatically to all questions. The second `fsck` got completely stuck from the beginning, so I disconnected the drive. Upon reconnecting it, the system wouldn't recognize it anymore, and it became noisy.

I tried searching on the web for such a similar sound, and from both these pages [[1]](http://datacent.com/datarecovery/hdd/samsung/HD502IJ) [[2]](http://datacent.com/hard_drive_sounds.php) the closest sound I found was the `IBM 40GB desktop hard drive with degraded media/heads rattles and squeals on spin up.`, but still it sounds different.

I have uploaded its sound [here](https://app.box.com/s/y9i6jdaf5en1v77wubkn), please take 30 seconds to listen to it. Also, please notice it changes the tone a bit every 7 seconds.

I'd like to know if it is possible to find out what is the problem and if there is a fix for it.

**EDIT**: the system recognizes it after I leave it spinning for a few minutes, and also the noise stops. I tried filling it with zeros, but my whole system locks after some time, which is unusual, considering it is a secondary hard drive connected via USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's obviously a drive failure. The noise sounds like the head is seeking constantly end-to-end, as if it couldn't locate the data tracks, which likely indicates a head or media failure.

It doesn't appear data recovery is important to you, since you said you used this drive for backups and you tried to zero-fill the drive (which would make data recovery difficult or impossible). In any case, you need to replace the drive.

Answer (score 4):

Your disk is dead, don't use it for anything but recovering the data.
Get a new disk and install your operating system from scratch.

If you don't have backups, install the dead disk as a second disk or in an external enclosure, then try to recover the data.
Don't keep that disk turning longer than is absolutely necessary, because its
state could still degrade.

Here are some free data-recovering tools :

[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) (initially created for photos, but now will recover many file-types)
[ddrescue](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100226123455346/ddrescue.html) (only for insistently copying disks)
[R-Studio for Linux](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/) (works similarly to ddrescue, but will also recover files)
[DiskInternals Linux Recovery](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-recovery/) (runs under Windows or via boot CD)

Some Linux live CDs are specialized in data recovery, such as [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage)
and [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=1&front_id=12).

An unrecoverable disk may be rendered recoverable for a certain time by
[Save a Failed Hard Drive in Your Freezer](http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux) (no joke, it sometimes works).

If you manage to save any data, never write it to the damaged disk -
any attempt to write to that disk will either fail or just increase the damage.

Professional disk recovery services may be available in your country,
but may typically cost around 1000 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

The hard disk is broken. Since they are mechanical devices, they break sooner or later. There is no simple fix for it.

You should buy a new hard drive and restore data from backups. If you have no backups, then there are data restoration services that might be able to retrieve the data. These services cost quite much though.